# Strange behaviour in biblatex @online without year

Tags: biblatex, online

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
%           natbib=true
        style=ieee,
        sorting=none,
        doi=false,
        isbn=false,
        url=true,
        urldate=long,
        ]{biblatex} % best for bibliography

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@Online{stack,
title     = {stackexchange},
url       = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/},
urldate   = {2016-08-30},
}
    \end{filecontents}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{urlseen = {Last accessed:},}

\addbibresource{references.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{stack}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives [image: this]

1. starting `().` should be removed.

`\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \ifentrytype{Online}{%
        \clearfield{labelyear}%
    }{%
}%
}` not working

2. `Available:` => `Available at:`
3. `(Last accessed: )` => without bracket

Please don't change filecontents.

Comment: `date`/`year` is normally a mandatory field and should - if at al possible - be given. There are very few situations where you could let it go and I believe websites without a clear date indicator is a prime example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `date`/`year` is a mandatory field `biblatex-ieee` expects there to be one and does not check if the year is missing to avoid empty brackets. We can do that - the check is inserted using the `xpatch` package to avoid rewriting the driver -

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}
  {\iffieldundef{year}{}{\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}}
  {}{}
```

Item 2 should be dealt with with

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{url = [Online]\adddot\addspace Available at,}
```

Finally, there is

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}
```

for the third point.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
%           natbib=true
        style=ieee,
        sorting=none,
        doi=false,
        isbn=false,
        url=true,
        urldate=long,
        ]{biblatex} % best for bibliography

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@Online{stack,
title     = {stackexchange},
url       = {https://tex.stackexchange.com/},
urldate   = {2016-08-30},
}
    \end{filecontents}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{urlseen = {Last accessed:},}

\addbibresource{references.bib}


\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}
  {\iffieldundef{year}{}{\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}}
  {}{}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{url = [Online]\adddot\addspace Available at,}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}

\begin{document}
\cite{stack}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [1] Stackexchange, [Online]. Available at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/ Last accessed: Aug. 30, 2016.